# Classification of irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider a semi-simple Lie group $G$ of rank $r$. Racah’s theorem states that $G$ has $r$ independent Casimir elements $C_i$. Let $D\colon G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ be an irreducible representation of $G$ on some vector space $V$. By Schur’s lemma, the Casimir elements are represented by multiples of the unit operator on $V$: $D(C_i)=c_i\mathbf{1}_V$.

**My question**: can two *inequivalent* irreducible representations $D,D'$ of $G$ on respective vector spaces $V,V'$ lead to the same constants of proportionality $c_i$? In other words, is it possible that both $D(C_i)=c_i\mathbf{1}_V$ and $D'(C_i)=c_i\mathbf{1}_{V’}$?

In the context of physics, $G$ is most often a group of linear operators and it is often stated that the eigenvalues of its Casimir operators can be used to uniquely classify its irreducible representations. Hence my question.

Comment: The discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158386/application-of-harish-chandra-theorem?rq=1) seems to answer your question in the affirmative. The eigenvalues of the Casimir elements determine the irreducible representations up to isomorphism. Note you need to look at all the Casimir elements - it is a fairly approachable calculation to see that the quadratic element for $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ has the same eigenvalues on a representation and its dual (the cubic element however changes sign on the dual)

Comment: Note since the Casimir elements live in the universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra none of this depends on the choice of group with given Lie algebra (apart from the actual existence of a group representation) so $G$ being linear or not isn't a problem.